A name for the Weyl group of $\frak{so_{2n}}$
For the $A$-series the Weyl group is the symmetric group $S_n$. For the $B$ and $C$ series the Weyl group is the hyperoctahedral group $\mathbb Z_2 \wr S_n$.
A) Does the $D$-series Weyl group $S_n \mathbb{Z}_2^{n-1}$ have a name?
B) For the exceptional groups, the Weyl group of $G_2$ is the dihedral group $D_6$. What about the other exceptional, do their Weyl groups have names?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group#Subgroups. I don't think there is any standard name for this group like "hyperoctahedral group" or "symmetric group."

Every Weyl group has a character that sends all reflections in long/short roots to $-1$, and reflections in short/long roots to $1$. (Which reflections are which depends on whether you call your root system $\mathsf C_n$ or $\mathsf B_n$.)  If you call all roots of $\mathsf A_n$ long/short, then this is the sign homomorphism.  From this point of view, I'd argue that $W(\mathsf D_n)$ is to the hyperoctahedral group as the alternating group is to $W(\mathsf A_n)$.  I'd dare to suggest "alternating hyperoctahedral group", but (1) it's pretty terrible and (2) I've never seen it used.

@LSpice: on the other hand "group of even signed permutations" is totally clear and sounds fine, if a bit wordy.

@SamHopkins, re, I'd argue that that terminology is a bit confusing since it sounds like it should include the even permutations, but doesn't.

(By the way, the standard symbol for wreath product is \wr. I edited accordingly.)

Thanks a lot for the $\wr$ edits!

@LSpice Indeed I now see how that could be confusing. For example, in this paper https://doi.org/10.37236/1836 the terms "even-signed permutations" and "signed even permutations" are both used, which seems unnecessarily confusing to me.

Maybe "special hyperoctahedral group"?

The first wreath now looks the wrong way round to me, and the second one just totally wrong because it's not even supposed to be a wreath product.

(I also take the opportunity to mention that my comment should have said that $W(\mathsf D_n)$ contains odd-as-unsigned permutations, not that it doesn't contain even-as-unsigned permutations. That is, my objection should have been that $W(\mathsf D_n) \cap W(\mathsf A_{n - 1})$ isn't the alternating subgroup of $W(\mathsf A_{n - 1})$, not that $W(\mathsf D_n)$ doesn't contain the alternating subgroup of $W(\mathsf A_{n - 1})$; of course the latter is false. @SamHopkins, thank you for reading my comment charitably as it was meant!)

I don't know where I first saw it, but I have seen the term "demihyperoctahedral group" used before, so if you're doing searches, that can sometimes pick up relevant papers.
As for the exceptional groups, the type E Weyl groups are all closely related to groups of Lie type over finite fields, so from that isomorphism they have names sort of. Look at the last 3 rows of
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group#List_of_irreducible_complex_reflection_groups
Type $E_6$ has many different realizations so not sure if any of those names would be most canonical.
As far as I know, the Weyl group of type $F_4$ is most cleanly described as the automorphisms of the "24-cell", a certain 4-dimensional polytope.
Some more detail can be found in Section 2.12 of Humphreys' book Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups.
